# AWS SES Reply-To header email requires verification?

Tags: amazon-ses

The AWS SES documentation states the Reply-To header email does not require pre-validation/verification. However if I include it, it rejects my request (works without).

`Reply-To: test@mysite.com`

Email address is not verified. The following identities failed the check in region EU-WEST-2: test@mysite.com

Comment: Is your account still in Sandbox mode?

Comment: @ceejayoz no I have 50,000 emails per 24-hour period quota